# Unable to display GeoChart zoomOut button

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I try to use geochart api. This api is latest one and few information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['geochart'],
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['Russia', 700]
          //['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          showZoomOut: true,
        };
        console.log("showZoomOut=" + options.showZoomOut);
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "zoomOut", function(){
          options.region = "world";
          console.log(options.region);
          chart.draw(data, options);        
        });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', function(r) {
          console.log(r);
          options.region = r.region;
          chart.draw(data, options);
        });
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width; 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

showZoomOut option is already true. But zoomButton is not displayed.
Documents is here
[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#showzoomout)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQXl.png)
I expect to display like this zoomButton.

Answer (score 0):

This question is resolved by myself.

zoomButton is supported only geomap. GeoChart is unavailable to apply it.